# C++ Assigning variables with 'compound names' using an external argument

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to read a .pdb file and hence I'm ending with a lot of variables in my code. In an effort to reduce them (and avoid Segmentation fault errors) I was wondering if I could assign array names in my code using an external argument.

The starting bit of my code foo.cpp looks like this-

```
/*All the relevant headers*/
using namespace std ;
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    ifstream input(argv[1],ios::out) ;
    string first(argv[2]) ;
    string second(argv[3]) ;
    string "first"ATOM[1000] ;
    string "second"ATOM[1000] ;
}
```

And I'm hoping that if I launch the program as ./foo.exe input C O, I want two arrays called CATOM and OATOM to be initialised.

If there is no second argument then the OATOM array should not get defined.

This would save me the trouble of having to make multiple arrays such as NATOM[1000], OATOM[1000] etc. since I can define them **within** the program.

Is this possible? For each 'O', 'C', 'N' etc there need to be about 8-10 long string arrays which is causing it to blow up.

I'm new to programming and I hope this question makes sense.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use a `std::map<std::string. std::vector>` to "name" what each "array" is.

Comment: Variable names only exist during compilation, but how would letting the user name the variables affect their number or the existence of segfaults?

Comment: You need to reformulate the problem that you want to solve. You're not really interested in the name of the array, because in c++ this information is discarded during compilation. So the question should rather deal with "how should I organize my program, so that I can ... (insert your problem in plain english here)".

Comment: I suspect that another one of your problems is using many large local arrays. Use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest creating a struct with array and a string variable containing the name of that array and then you just search the structs by name.

A more elegant solution is using std::map like @NathanOliver suggested. Runtime changes of variable names are not possible (or logical) within c++ as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to change or set variable names at run time.

However, *map* (also known as *dictionary* or *associative array*) is a data structure that allows you to associate key objects (such as a string) to value objects (such as an array) and it possibly fits your needs. There is an implementation of map in the standard library, that you can use.